# Implementation propagation_const in prio C++17 version

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, c++14, propagation

It is the following example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class B{

    public:
    void foo() const{
        std::cout << "foo const" << std::endl;
    }
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo non-const" << std::endl;
    }
};
class A{

    public:
    void bar() const{
        std::cout << "bar const" << std::endl;
        b_->foo();
    }
    void bar() {
        std::cout << "bar non-const" << std::endl;
        b_->foo();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<B> b_{std::make_shared<B>()};
};

int main(){
    A const a;
    a.bar();
}
```

Based on standard correctly the const is not propagated and foo non-const is called. My question how to implement propagation_const in version before C++17?

Comment: Are you talking about `std::experimental::propagate_const`? Why are you saying "before C++17", what does `propagate_const` have to do with C++17?  What version are you using?

Comment: Yes exactly. A implementation similar to std::experimental::propagate_const

Comment: Take a newer compiler and copy its implementation?

Comment: A simpler than this in inside gcc?

Comment: you could convert `b_` to `shared_ptr<const B>` in `bar() const;` though this would not be too convenient